# React- change input value causes error

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I have problem with changing value of `input` during `onChange`,

```
 handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <label className={s.captionLabel}>{this.props.caption}</label>
          <input className={this.props.modal? s.modalTextInput : s.textInput} onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} ref="inp" disabled={!this.state.isChecked} type="text" />
          <label className={s.unitLabel}>{this.props.unit}</label>
          <input className={s.boxInput} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.toggleChange.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I am still getting error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I tried `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this}` , after this I didn't receive this error message but I couldn't change value of input. In extract of `event.target.value` I am getting value like a 1,01,02 and so on.... but value don't change anymore (I just cant overwrite value in input ). So any tips what I have to do?

Comment: How does you constructor look? It should call super, bind you change handler and set this.state to some initial value.

Comment: If you use `es6 class` method for the component, you'll have to manually `bind this`. Regarding input value, if you console log `this.state.value` on render and type something on your input, what value will be logged ?

Comment: @Tushar Khatiwada When i have manually bind this, i cant overwrite input. so my render dont run. I have default zero values in my inputs , and i just cant delete them or overwrite. @Scarysize In constructor i have `super(props)`, `value: '0'` and `this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)`

Comment: @LukášUnzeitig Try this: In your `handleChange(event)` comment `this.setState` and write `console.log(event)`. Type in anything and see what logs in your debugger console.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada its a long message :D - `Object { dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: Object, nativeEvent: input, type: "change", target: <input.Inputs_modalTextInput_2d6>, currentTarget: <input.Inputs_modalTextInput_2d6>, eventPhase: 3, bubbles: true, cancelable: false, timeStamp: 1469599236447, 6 and next… }` what exactly am i looking for?

Comment: @LukášUnzeitig Looking at that output, seems like `event.target.value` is undefined. Try this method instead: `<input className={this.props.modal? s.modalTextInput : s.textInput} onChange={(text) => this.setState({value: text})} value={this.state.value} ref="inp" disabled={!this.state.isChecked} type="text" />`

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada still without possibility of changing inputs value :/

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada have it !!! :D My function shouldComponentUpdate blocked this re-render...  however thanks a lot !

Comment: @LukášUnzeitig Did it work? I found a different solution rather. Try changing your `value={this.state.value}` to `defaultValue={this.state.value}`.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada I found, when i wanna control my form, i have to use value instead of defaultValue, your solution text => ... wrote on input [Object object] so i put my solution back , delete `shouldComponentUpdate` and now everything works right. Like i said, this method blocked my re-render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind your function in `constructor` method

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { value: 0 }
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Current value: {this.state.value}</h1>
          <label>{this.props.caption}</label>
          <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} ref="inp" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example name="World" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Comment: already have, although without error, but now with no possibility of value change

Comment: have it !!! :D My function shouldComponentUpdate blocked this re-render... however thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

exactly my code looks like -

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      isChecked: true,
      value: '0'
    };
    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);

  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return this.props.inputValue != nextProps.inputValue;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('inputWillReciveProps',nextProps.inputValue);
    this.setState({
      value: nextProps.inputValue
    })
  }

  handleChange(event){
    console.log(event);/*
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });*/
  }

  render(){
    console.log('Inputrender',this.props.inputValue);
    return(
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <label className={s.captionLabel}>{this.props.caption}</label>
          <input className={this.props.modal? s.modalTextInput : s.textInput} onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} ref="inp" disabled={!this.state.isChecked} type="text" />
          <label className={s.unitLabel}>{this.props.unit}</label>
          <input className={s.boxInput} type="checkbox" checked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={this.toggleChange.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  toggleChange(){
    this.setState({
      isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` looks not very good. Remove this function